# Why accessing ReadFileEx's input buffer prematurely can cause data corruption?

Tags: c, winapi, readfile, corruption

[`ReadFileEx`'s documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365468.aspx) says:

> Accessing the input buffer while a read operation is using the buffer may lead to corruption of the data read into that buffer. Applications must not read from, write to, reallocate, or free the input buffer that a read operation is using until the read operation completes.

This is the first time I've ever heard of reading data causing corruption.
So my question is, *why* does that happen? How can a *read* operation possibly cause data corruption?
What's going on underneath that causes this?

#### Update:

I noticed an interesting sentence on [`ReadFile`'s page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467.aspx):

> The `ReadFile` function may fail with `ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_QUOTA`, which means the calling process's buffer could not be page-locked.

Maybe this is related to the answer?

Comment: Pure speculation, but one could imagine that the implementation modified the protection flags of the underlying pages and waited for a page fault to signal read completion. Then you reading from the pages while the operation was in progress would result in corrupted data being returned. Similar to what is described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/27/773741.aspx

Comment: @user786653: That's a *very* interesting point! Though it makes me wonder, where would the page fault handler be? I wonder if it's inside `WaitForXxx` or something...

Comment: It just doesn't make sense to try to read the buffer content while the overlapped I/O operation is in progress.  You have no idea what you'll get.  Speculating what may go wrong when you do anyway is not useful and unanswerable.  And off topic, the FAQ is quite clear about that: "practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face".

Comment: There's nothing "unanswerable" about it; just because you and I don't know the answer doesn't mean it doesn't have one, especially when the documentation so explicitly mentions the problem. And the problem couldn't be more practical: knowing how your tools work makes you use them better. There's no reason to constrain yourself to a single abstraction level and have zero idea what the heck is going on underneath. But heck, go ahead and vote to close if it makes you feel you accomplished something great today.

Comment: This isn't really a practical programming question. The rules say don't do it, so don't do it. The reason why doesn't change the rules. Suppose I said the reason is that "on certain hardware, reads can trigger latching." Does that change in any way how you write your code?

Comment: @RaymondChen: If *that* was hypothetically the reason, then it wouldn't affect how I write Win32 code, but a priori I don't know the reason, or whether or not it will affect me. However: I am currently studying EE too (digital circuits at the moment), so that would actually make me learn something when I'm writing Verilog -- so I would end up learning something anyway, even if it turns out not to affect me on the Win32 side. But again, a priori, without knowing the reason beforehand, I obviously can't know whether or not it will affect me.

Comment: On the other hand, consider what would happen if the reason was "because of optimization technique X". In that scenario it certainly *could* affect me because once I learn about that optimization, I might employ it somewhere else in my application where I'm doing something I/O intensive. But, again, depends on the reason, I can't tell you whether or not it will affect how I write code beforehand. It might end up being useless, but I can't know that before I know the answer, and I certainly don't want other people judge its uselessness for me without telling me the answer!

Comment: Those are not specific programming problems. They are solutions looking for a problem.

Comment: Gaining an understanding of why something isn't permitted can be useful. Sure, you still have to follow the rules even if you don't understand why the rules are the rules. But there's still value in understanding why a rule might exist. For example, John Regehr's articles on undefined behavior in C (such as http://blog.regehr.org/archives/759) are helpful for understanding why certain constructs that might appear just fine at first glance are in fact undefined behavior. And that understanding might help programmers spot those dodgy patterns.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure so I'm pretty open to comments but I guess:

`ReadFileEx` is implemented to use `NtReadFile` (more or less it's just a thin wrapper around it). `NtReadFile` does a lot of stuff but it uses `IoBuildAsynchronousFsdRequest` (or `IoBuildSynchronousFsdRequest`) to perform its task. From [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;Q326315) we know that:

> If the target device object is set up do direct i/o (DO_DIRECT_IO), then IoBuildAsynchronousFsdRequest creates an MDL to describe the buffer and **locks the pages**.

(emphasis is mine)

Then I guess they call `MmProbeAndLockPages` with `IoWriteAccess`, this is done by the driver in kernel mode then the user supplied buffer (in user mode) can't even be accessed for read.

I don't know what will happen if you do it, probably a SEH exception will be thrown and your code will fail.

**EDIT**
As pointed out in the edited question even the `ReadFile` function forbids the user to read from the buffer until operation has been completed and it may returns `ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_QUOTA`:

> The ReadFile function may fail with ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_QUOTA, which means the calling process's buffer could not be page-locked.

At least this makes clear that `ReadFile` (where the buffer isn't provided by the user) will allocate a page and it'll **lock** it (ok it has been said in the article I linked too...). It remains to understand if the corruption (if any, about this I strongly agree with @David) can occur with user defined buffer too (where a lock on the page, as pointed out by @Ben, most of times is impossible).

I don't think it uses page faults to detect buffer overruns simply because it knows the required amount of data *before* the call then it can allocate it once.

**So why data can be corrupted?**
After all everything here can due to an error but not to data corruption. This is a big guess but there was a known issue about `MmProbeAndLockPages`:

> This issue occurs because of a race condition in the Memory Manager. When a driver calls the MmProbeAndLockPages routine, this routine may read some data that is being modified by another thread. Therefore, data corruption occurs. Depending on how the corrupted data is used, the application or the system may crash.

It's hard to say if this issue has been resolved at very low level or if can still exploit if application does something weird...

Comment: Crashes make sense, but a corruption? That's what confuses me. Anyway, +1 for the info. :)

Comment: A closer look will show that the semantics of `ReadFile` don't permit the kernel to do anything as drastic as marking the entire page write-only.  (Well, maybe if you've opened the file for direct unbuffered I/O, in which case you're required to use entire pages as the buffer)

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm not sure, after all you supply a buffer and they _ask_ you to don't even read from it so it may even mark the page for write-only. Anyway I guess (again) they ask you to don't even read because **you may make their call to MmProbleAndLockPages to fail** (what if you use the same buffer in a routine that deep inside calls MmProbeAndLockPages?)

Comment: @Adriano: There's no prohibition on continuing to access other data on the same page as the buffer.

Comment: @Mehrdad ...then their call will fail (inside NtReadFile) and it will cause data corruption (where and how the exception is handled inside the ReadFileEx call stack?)

Comment: @Ben Voigt's point about data on the same page as the buffer is a great one.

Comment: @Mehrdad **it applies (_there's  not prohibition to access other data on the same page_) only when the user supplies the buffer** (OS won't lock it) but it _may_ not be the case when the buffer is allocated by the OS. You have the same sentence in ReadFile documentation (where you can't provide a buffer and it's always allocated by OS). I don't think it uses page faults simply because it knows the required buffer size in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the corruption when you read from the I/O buffer results from the race condition -- the buffer may be partially filled in when you read from it, and the order in which it is filled in is unspecified.  In addition, Windows could store anything in there during the time it owns the buffer -- you aren't guaranteed to see either the prior content or the data from the file.

What you can be sure of is that **it isn't related to access violations when reading from the buffer**, because it's perfectly legal to continue accessing other data in the same page.  Only the buffer itself is forbidden to your use.  Now, when the file is open for direct unbuffered I/O (`FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`), *and the volume sector size is a multiple of the memory page size*, then, the buffer is required to correspond to a sequence of complete pages, so the kernel has more freedom at that point.  But that's a very particular set of conditions, and it's rare for the sector size to exceed the memory page size.

Comment: I don't think that's what they meant. They clearly say that the mere action of reading *causes* corruption *"of the data read into that buffer"*, **not** corruption *"of the application state"* or something vague like that.

Comment: @Mehrdad: You read the buffer, and find unexpected data present there.  Many people would describe that as corruption... even if the correct data is later present at the time the operation completes.

Comment: It's not a corruption of *the data*, it's a corruption of *your state*. There's a clear difference and what you're saying is not what they're describing. (Also, food for thought: if all I wanted the data for was help generating a random number, then a race condition would be the perfect thing!)

Comment: @Mehrdad: Race conditions rarely generate data with strong randomness properties.

Comment: So do you mean that nothing "bad" will happen but just you'll read garbage? It makes sense but I can't see why they should warn you to don't read...noone would expect valid data before the call ends.

Comment: @Mehrdad: It is corruption in a broad sense (you can read arbitrary data if you don't read at the approved time), not in the narrow sense (at the approved time, the data will be correct).

Comment: @BenVoigt: The documentation isn't being broad, though. Its sentence is quite specific (they didn't just say it causes "corruption", they went ahead and described *what* corruption) and it's really hard to interpret it differently.

Answer (score 0):

There are two sentences. First of all:

> Accessing the input buffer while a read operation is using the buffer may lead to corruption of the data read into that buffer.

Followed by:

> Applications must not read from, write to, reallocate, or free the input buffer that a read operation is using until the read operation completes.

The documentation does not explicitly say that **each** of the actions mentioned in the second sentence may lead to the corruption described in the first sentence. It says the following:

1. Accessing input buffer during read may corrupt that buffer, and
2. Do not read, write, reallocate or free the buffer during read.

So, as I interpret the documentation, it does not state that reading from the buffer during a read operation can corrupt it.

Comment: Yeah, so in your own words, if you read the data (2), then you can be penalized by corruption of the data you read (1). Confirms exactly what I'm asking.

Comment: No, that's not what I meant at all. The documentation states that accessing the buffer may corrupt it. It does not state what form of access may lead to a corruption.

Comment: Yeah, because *any* of the forms of access they described can lead to the corruption. That's why they didn't say "write" instead of just "access"; read is a form of access. What's the point of mentioning reading otherwise?

Comment: Note that the text does not say that accessing the buffer *will* corrupt the data, only that it *may*. It is saying that the operating system is allowed to optimize on the assumption that you will not access the buffer during the I/O, and if you violate the assumption, then the integrity of the data is not guaranteed.